# How to manipulate the DOM in a BHO

Tags: c++, dom, bho

im trying to manipulate the DOM of a website in my BHO. I wrote in C++ but I cant figure out how to do it. Here are to different approaches I tried. The second one isnt really manipulating the DOM but I figured it was worth a try...

```
//get parent node
IHTMLDOMNode* parent;
ielem->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDOMNode, (void**)&parent);

//get child node
IHTMLElement* child_element;
doc2->createElement(L"a", &child_element);
IHTMLDOMNode* child_node;
child_element->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDOMNode, (void**)&child_element);

//Create Value
VARIANT value;
value.vt = VT_BSTR;
value.bstrVal = L"TEST";

//set value
child_node->put_nodeValue(value);

//append child
parent->appendChild(child_node, &child_node);
```

The other way I tried was this:

```
//initialize
IHTMLElement* element;
BSTR* innerhtml;
ielem->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement, (void**)&element);

//overwrite the content
element->put_innerHTML(L"<a href=\"http://www.google.de\">testytest</a>");
element->get_innerHTML(innerhtml);

//check for success
MessageBox(0, *innerhtml, L"Titel", 0);
delete innerhtml;
```

Comment: Looks pretty reasonable to me (give or take a few quibbles like `delete innerhtml` instead of `SysFreeString(innerhtml)`). Where are you running this code? Are you sure it is really executing?

Comment: Somehow the BHO wasnt getting registered though I didnt change anything... Now that it works when i try the put_innerHtml variant it obviously does something, since the elements that are overwritten arent there anymore, but the link appears nowhere in the HTMLCode.

Comment: OK, and where are you running the code (i.e. in response to which browser event)?

Comment: The code responses to the DocumentComplete event. The error was that I was looking at the "Display Sourcecode" option of IE, which only shows the Code IE received from the website in the first place. With the developer tools I can see the changes.